# How can I move a user to a specific voice channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a system using Python that when a user joins a Discord VC by a specific ID, it moves them to a specific output/destination voice channel.

I was wondering how to do this correctly. If possible, use pairs to have multiple Source to Destination IDs using pairs or arrays.

Comment: You should consider next time to add code for what you tried and check out the Stackoverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **possible**, by using the `on_voice_state_update` event, which offers the [discord.py library](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_voice#discord.on_voice_state_update).

First, you check if the user **joined** the `voice` channel and **after that**, you get the **destination** `voice` channel object and move the user to it.

Don't forget to replace `DESTINATION_CHANNEL_ID` and `SOURCE_CHANNEL_ID`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member: discord.Member, before: discord.VoiceState, after: discord.VoiceState):
    # check if the user joined a voice channel
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
    
       # if you want to include multiple sources and destinations, you should check for the channel_id.
       if after.channel.id = SOURCE_CHANNEL_ID:
          destination_voice = member.guild.get_channel(DESTINATION_CHANNEL_ID)
       
          # Move the user to the destination voice channel.
          await member.move_to(destination_voice, reason="Moved by bot")
    
       # check for other channel
       elif after.channel.id = SOURCE_CHANNEL_ID2:
          destination_voice = member.guild.get_channel(DESTINATION_CHANNEL_ID2)
       
          # Move the user to the destination voice channel.
          await member.move_to(destination_voice, reason="Moved by bot")
```

Comment: How could I use multiple Destinations and Sources with in the same client.event

Comment: I edited my answer, in order to allow multiple destiantions and sources.

Comment: Is it possible to allow the ability to drag users into that vc and then the bot to drag them?

Comment: @Kano if you include the `await member.move_to` line, the bot should move the users to the destination channel - doesn't he do it?

Comment: The bot moves it, Im Wondering if a user can move another user into the channel for it to activate. It doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yeah, thats a new question, create a new post and I will answer it. :)